# runModalForWindow throttles http requests

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, modal-dialog, runloop

I have url connection, which normally works fine

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                              delegate:delegate];
```

But when I create a modal window, no request ever receives response:

```
[NSApp runModalForWindow:window];
```

If I comment this line out, thus creating a 'standard' window, everything works.

I tried implementing all methods from NSURLConnectionDelegate, not a single of them called.

I suspect this is something about 'run loops', but have little experience in this area. Does anybody have experience in this?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're targeting 10.5+, you can tell the `NSURLConnection` to also run in `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode` (the mode your current thread's runloop would be in while presenting a modal view) via

```
-(void)scheduleInRunLoop:(NSRunLoop *)aRunLoop forMode:(NSString *)mode
```

where `aRunLoop` would probably be `[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` and the `mode` would be `NSModalPanelRunLoopMode`.  More info in the [`NSURLConnection` doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you're supporting earlier OSs, you may have to get creative (i.e. with multithreading).  Good discussion of this issue pre-10.5 [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/208824-runloops-and-nsurlconnection.html).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't bumped into the situation you're having, but I suggest spawning and starting a connection in background thread.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the same problem that didn't get the delegate method called when using NSURLConnection in a Modal Window.

after some investigation, following code resolve it.

```
NSURLConnection* conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requst delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
[conn scheduleRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentLoop] forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode];
[conn start];
```

However, when connectionDidFinishLoading called, [NSApp stopModal] doesn't work, need call [NSApp abortModal] instead.